# Is there a way to match an image on my pc with a location in google maps?

Tags: image, search

Like the title says.

I have an image on my PC and want to find out where it was taken.

Is there a possibility to find the place by google maps ?

Thanks

Comment: Not really about programming, is it?

Comment: http://images.google.com/

Comment: Thank you all for you answers. I realize that something like this is impossible. Thank you once again for all your answers. Wish you all the best

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't related to programming.

Comment: I wish SO was more friendly to newbies.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking might be possible.  But the scope of what you are asking is near impossible, if not impossible.  It also seems unlikely that such a search would find a result you are looking for.

If you are just trying to place where a picture was taken, you would likely have far more luck, in much shorter time, posting the picture, as well as your best guess to narrow down the area, to a site such as Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Try running *jhead* on the image and see if it contains GPS coordinates. It is free [here](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).

Or, if you don't mind uploading your image to a web-service to view the GPS data, you can upload it to [here](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?url=http://regex.info/i/_JEF1348.jpg).

If you get the GPS cooridnates, you can type them in to maps.google.com, like this

```
52.785,-2.012
```

and hit enter and the map will centre on your location.